# Find the maximum value of | Ai - Aj | + | i - j |:

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, array

[hackerearth.com practice problem *Can you solve it?*](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/can-you-solve-it/):

> Given an array **'A'** consisting of **'n'** integers, find the **maximum value** of the following expression:
>   \$\lvert A_i - A_j\rvert + \lvert i - j\rvert\$

where \$A_i\$ is the element of the array at the i-th position (0-indexed array)

My solution:

```py
def solve(n,l):
    ans=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if ans < (abs(l[i]-l[j])+abs(i-j)):
                ans=(abs(l[i]-l[j])+abs(i-j))
                print(ans)


t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input())
    l = list(map(int,input().split()))
solve(n,l)
```

This code passes all the sample test cases but when I finally submit the code
for two inputs it shows *wrong* and
for all the other inputs it shows *time limit exceeded*.

Kindly point out what is wrong and what can be done in order to get the correct output.

Comment: The description says to **maximize** the value, but the code looks like it is trying to find the **minimum** (`if ans < (abs(l[i]-l[j])+abs(i-j))`)

Comment: (@RootTwo you seem to expect comparisons done *current ? candidate*, the code shows *candidate < current*.)

Comment: While advice about code giving results as specified, but failing to meet requirements in any other way is on topic, code giving *wrong* results is [not ready for review at CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RootTwo: Personally, I always try to write (in C): `if (a<b) a=b;`  Then I split it on two lines, and line up the as and bs.  This way, at least you can see the are the same variables.

Comment: Try input vector 3 1 5 1.
Generate and try other input files.

Comment: @DavidG. Well, when I paste code & input (from the hackerearth page hyperlinked), I do *not* get the required output, not even for the 1st example. While I don't think the error hard to spot, the code is *not ready for review*. The question is closed so it is not answered (as it should not) until the code is fixed.

Comment: @greybeard: I thought I tested that case.  conceeded.

Comment: @DavidG. updated the code try copy pasting the code you will get the required output for the 1st example..click on compile and test button...

Comment: @MadhuraankB:  Sorry, that was more bad luck that got you the right results.  Make a number of inputs, and try them all.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The minor problem is that you are printing the result in the wrong place.

The major problem is that `n` may be up to 100,000.  This means you need to run 10,000,000,000 of your inner test.  And you may have only 0.02 seconds to do that.

The trick to dealing with that is probably to determine the maximum possible score of a given `i` and `l[i]`, and skip the inner loop if it isn't worth it.  As part of this, you might find it beneficial to determine the range of the `l[]` values.

As an example, if you determine that all `l[i]<=5`, then it isn't worth looking at `i>6` and `i<n-6` (or thereabouts... I'm not positive about the border condition).

Comment: Your last paragraph, where all l[i] are less than 6, isn't true if some l[i] is very negative, say -100.  You need to find the smallest and largest values and take their difference.

Comment: @RayButterworth, True, but the full problem statement included: `n` up to 100,000, and `l` values from 0 to 100,000, up to 100 "problems" in the input, and a 2 second time limit.

Answer (score 1):

`solve()` shouldn't print anything, much less all the intermediate results.
It should end with `return ans` and the main program should print that final result.

You'll get the same answer for (i,j) as for (j,i), so for the inner loop j never needs to be less than i.

The expression `abs(l[i] - l[j]) + abs(i - j)` gets calculated twice.  Instead, assign the value to a temporary variable and use that twice.

David G.'s suggestion, of finding the maximum possible contribution of the `l[i] - l[j]` term and using that to restrict the range of i and j, is perhaps the most effective optimization.

Comment: One can't simply restrict the range of i and j.  One can determine that no j will produce a better score than the current best score.  I'm not sure if this means you can restrict to j>i.

Comment: @DavidG., say `l[i]=X; l[j]=Y`.  If you compute `|X-Y| + |i-j|` you'll get the same value as when you compute `|Y-X| + |j-i|`, so there's no point in doing both calculations.  The extra one can be avoided simply by assuming `i ≤ j`.